# Generic findById with Entity Framework and composite keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have this generic version of a `findById()` method (`KeyType` and `EntityType` are template parameters at the class level):

```
public EntityType findById(KeyType key)
{
    log.LogDebugStart();
    log.LogDebug("id=" + key);

    EntityType data;

    using (ObjectContextWrapper contextWrapper = TransactionHelper.GetContextWrapper())
    {
        Entities bdd = contextWrapper.GetContext();

        DbSet<EntityType> set = bdd.Set<EntityType>();

        data = set.Find(key);
    }

    log.LogDebugEnd();
    return data;
}
```

It works well with single-column keys (ex: KeyType = long) but I can't get it to work with composite primary key (Ex: KeyType : long[]).

The exception I get:

> The number of primary key values passed must match number of primary
>   key values defined on the entity. Parameter name: keyValues

The entities are generated from the database with the help of an `.edmx` file. Both columns in my case are set to primary key. In the debugger, I see very well that key is of type short[2].

I thought it could be linked with the fact that my method doesn't take a "params" argument, and that somehow the entire array would be passed as a single param to the `Find()` method, but it should be fine as long as I pass an array to my `findById()` method...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert the key values into an object array, i.e., `object[]`.

I suggest you replace this:

```
data = set.Find(key);
```

with this:

```
if(key is Array)
{
    data = set.Find((key as IEnumerable).Cast<object>().ToArray());
}
else
{
    data = set.Find(key);
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I knew it was something like that but I couldn't figure out the right way to cast my parameter...

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `params`? `params` of `object` will solve this problem.

```
public EntityType findById(params object[] keys)
{
    log.LogDebugStart();
    log.LogDebug("id=" + keys.Aggregate((a, b) => a.ToString() + ", " + b.ToString()));

    EntityType data;

    using (ObjectContextWrapper contextWrapper = TransactionHelper.GetContextWrapper())
    {
        Entities bdd = contextWrapper.GetContext();

        DbSet<EntityType> set = bdd.Set<EntityType>();

        data = set.Find(keys);
    }

    log.LogDebugEnd();
    return data;
}
```

Be aware that `Find` method only accepts an array of `object`. Take a look https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.113).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1

Comment: The fact that my parameter was an array of short was probably the problem, thanks. I ended up using Yacoub's solution but you helped me understand what was wrong. Thanks.